# Why is the following `css` construction not valid?

Tags: css

I want to use `calc` function but it is too simple.

```css
#data {
  background: #333333;
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
  height: calc(data.width/4)px;
  margin-top: 3%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 0px solid #333333;
}
```

Comment: What is `data.width`? css won't recognize that..

Comment: See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Comment: Check fiddle: [Height is quarter width](http://jsfiddle.net/444zzx7k/1/)

Comment: Please describe in words what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: *Why is the following `сss` construction not valid?* Because it's invalid syntax, both because of `data.width`, and because of the placement of `px`. I would suggest retitling your question to say something like "make div height 25% of width".

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because data.width isn't available, you can however use  variables to achieve what you are wanting.

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
#data{
  --width: 70%;
  background-color:blue;
  width: var(--width);
  height: calc(var(--width)/4);
 }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="data"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand you want height to be 1/4th the width.

This should do what you want:

```css
#data{
  background-color:blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25vw;
 }
```

```html
<div id="data"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, CSS currently doesn't allow using actual dimensions of the elements in calculations. The [`calc()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) only allows operations with known values of the same type (e.g. lengths expressed in different length units).

To make the element with constant proportions (as your code implies) you can either:

1. Use viewport relative units, e.g.

```css
#data {
  background: #333333;
  float: left;
  width: 70vw;
  /* note the white spaces around "/" and no extra units */
  height: calc(70vw / 4);
  /* or just height: 17.5vw; */
  margin-top: 3%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 0px solid #333333;
}
```

```html
<div id="data"></div>
```

2. Use [the padding hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10441480/2533215) (in this case, you will need absolute position for your `div` content):

```css
#data {
  background: #333333;
  float: left;
  width: 70vw;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: calc(70vw / 4);
  margin-top: 3%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 0px solid #333333;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="data"></div>
```